# SQL LEFT JOIN on three table with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

i want to get information from three table like :

Item

```
itemId  Name   Quantity Price  
1       Pen    100      1,0
2       Pencil 100      0,5
3       Glue   20       1,5
```

ItemFiles

```
itemId fileId
1      1001
1      1002
1      1003
2      2001
3      3001
3      3002
```

phisicsFile

```
fileId Filename 
1001   order_101_20170621.pdf
1002   delivery_404_20170627.pdf
1003   payement_20170630.pdf
2001   order_102_20170623.pdf
3001   order_103_20170624.pdf
3002   delivery_404_20170627.pdf
```

I need to have one single query a result like this

```
Name    Quantity    Price     Order Delivery   Payed
Pen         100       1,0      True   True    True
```

or

```
Pencil      100       0,5      True   False   False
```

or

```
Glue         20       1,5      True   True    False
```

i try something like this

```
SELECT
     I.itemId                           AS Id,
    CASE 
            WHEN FS.Filename like '%'Order'%' THEN 'True' 
            ELSE 'False' 
    END                                                        AS Order


FROM       Item  I

 left join 
ItemFiles on I.itemId = IF.itemId
left join phisicsFile PF on (IF.file_id = PF.fileId AND PF.Filename like '%order%')

WHERE  I.itemId= @itemId
```

But i get duplicate row in result

Comment: Not sure what you expect for output. And what does "duplicate row in result" mean? From the data and query you posted you would not get a duplicate row. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `LEFT JOIN`, just join and `GROUP BY`. Then use conditional count to check the presence of each file type.

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/RKPY35772)**

```
SELECT I.[itemId], I.[Name], I.[Quantity], I.[Price],
       CAST( COUNT(CASE WHEN P.Filename like '%order%' THEN 1 END) as bit) as [Orders],
       CAST( COUNT(CASE WHEN P.Filename like '%delivery%' THEN 1 END) as bit) as [Delivery],
       CAST( COUNT(CASE WHEN P.Filename like '%payement%' THEN 1 END) as bit) as [Payment]
FROM Items I
JOIN ItemFiles  F
  ON I.[itemId] = F.[itemId]
JOIN phisicsFile P
  ON F.[fileId] = P.[fileId]
GROUP BY   I.[itemId], I.[Name], I.[Quantity], I.[Price]
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Item', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Item;

CREATE TABLE #Item (
    ItemId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    Name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Quantity INT NOT NULL,
    Price MONEY NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #Item (ItemId, Name, Quantity, Price) VALUES 
(1, 'Pen', 100, 1.0),
(2, 'Pencil', 100, 0.5),
(3, 'Glue', 20, 1.5);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ItemFiles', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #ItemFiles;

CREATE TABLE #ItemFiles (
    ItemId INT NOT NULL,
    FileId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ItemId, FileId)
    );
INSERT #ItemFiles (ItemId, FileId) VALUES
(1, 1001),
(1, 1002),
(1, 1003),
(2, 2001),
(3, 3001),
(3, 3002);

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PhisicsFile', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #PhisicsFile;

CREATE TABLE #PhisicsFile (
    FieldId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    FileName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #PhisicsFile (FieldId, FileName) VALUES
(1001, 'order_101_20170621.pdf'),
(1002, 'delivery_404_20170627.pdf'),
(1003, 'payement_20170630.pdf'),
(2001, 'order_102_20170623.pdf'),
(3001, 'order_103_20170624.pdf'),
(3002, 'delivery_404_20170627.pdf');

--=================================================

SELECT 
    i.ItemId,
    i.Name,
    i.Quantity,
    i.Price,
    [Order] = CASE WHEN xif.HasOrder = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END,
    Delivery = CASE WHEN xif.HasDelivery = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END,
    Payement = CASE WHEN xif.HasPayement = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False'END
FROM 
    #Item i
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT 
            HasOrder = MAX(CASE WHEN pf.FileName LIKE 'order%' THEN 1 END),
            HasDelivery = MAX(CASE WHEN pf.FileName LIKE 'delivery%' THEN 1 END),
            HasPayement = MAX(CASE WHEN pf.FileName LIKE 'payement%' THEN 1 END)
        FROM 
            #ItemFiles ifi
            JOIN #PhisicsFile pf
                ON ifi.FileId = pf.FieldId
        WHERE 
            i.ItemId = ifi.ItemId
        ) xif;
```

HTH,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

```
select Id,Name,Quantity,Price,
    case when [order] = 1 then 'true' else 'false' end as [order],
    case when [delivery]=1 then 'true' else 'false' end as [delivery],
    case when [payement]=1 then 'true' else 'false' end as [payement]
from 
(SELECT
     I.itemId AS Id,
     I.Name,
     I.Quantity,
     I.Price,
     SUBSTRING(PF.Filename,0,charindex('_',PF.Filename))  stat                               
FROM       #Item  I
INNER join #ItemFiles Itf on I.itemId = Itf.itemId
INNER join #phisicsFile PF on Itf.fileId = PF.fileId) as s
PIVOT
(
count(stat) for stat IN ([order],[delivery],[payement])
) as p
```

If you are using sql 2016 then you can use STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator ) instead of substring.

Comment: instead of `CASE` you could use `CAST([order] as bit)`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TEMP AS 
(
    SELECT A.* , 
    CASE WHEN C.FILENAME LIKE '%ORDER%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'ORDER'  , 
    CASE WHEN C.FILENAME LIKE '%DELIVERY%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'DELIVERY' , 
    CASE WHEN C.FILENAME LIKE '%payement%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'PAYMENT'  
    FROM ITEM AS A 
    INNER JOIN ITEMFILES AS B ON A.ITEMID = B.ITEMID  
    INNER JOIN PHISICSfILE AS C ON B.FILEID = C.FILEID 
)    
SELECT ITEMID , NAME , QUANTITY , 
       SUM([ORDER]) AS 'ORDER'  , 
       SUM(DELIVERY) AS 'DELIVERY' , 
       SUM(PAYMENT) AS 'PAYED'
FROM TEMP 
GROUP BY  ITEMID , NAME , QUANTITY
```

Comment: Your answer is very similar to mine. But a few things:  single quotes mean string, so your alias should be enclosed in bracket `[ORDER]`. OP result ask for `true/false` you need `CAST(SUM([order]) as bit)` to convert the sum result.